# Uninstall file from Apache Tomcat Web Server

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I have a website deployed on an apache web server. I am using a windows installer to deploy and un-deploy this website from the server. During the uninstall I am just removing the .war from the webapp directory of the tomcat. Now when I do this the tomcat automatically removes all the folders created when it unpacked the war file. But it takes some time to remove those folders.

I want to know if there is a way to force tomcat to remove the folder immediately by communicating to it with some external tool eg a script, xml-rpc etc?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to issues with file and/or jar locking, particularly on Windows. There are two options available on the Context configuration level to minimize the impact of these (antiJARLocking  is a subset of antiResourceLocking).

Edit the file in `<tomcat-root>/conf/context.xml` and modify the `<Context>` element to include the `antiResourceLocking` attribute as follows:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="true">
```

For further information regarding context configuration options, have a look in the docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Comment: I tried this but it is still taking some time before it removes the website folder. What difference this had is very difficult to notice and I am still trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of delay are you experiencing?

Comment: This time is not fixed. Sometimes it takes seconds and sometimes it takes just under a minute. I was thinking if its possible to invoke tomcat to remove the website folder as soon as we remove the 'war' file.